# Phonegap Childbrowser onLocationChanged (iOS)

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, childbrowser

I need the URL of the current childBrowser window.. I've tried with

```
function doThis(){
var location;
var cb = window.plugins.ChildBrowser;
cb.onLocationChange = function(loc){ location = loc; }
alert(location);
}
```

in my body

```
<a href="#" onclick="doThis()">Do this</a>
```

But whenever I add the line with cb.onLocationChange, my app doesn't respond anymore..
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
cb.onLocationChange = function(loc){
    location = loc; 
    alert(location);
}
```